# importing from packages with conflicting names

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, import, package

I have 2 external jars in my referenced libraries.

Both of the jars have a package with the same name.

Is there any way to specify which jar i want to use in the import or a way to work around this?

[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: why do you need both? most likely, you just need one.

Comment: Only use one MongoDB driver. Choose one and remove the other jar completly.

Answer (score 1):

In the file where you are using the class, you have to give the full class name.

public com.mongodb.connection getDbDetail(){}

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are two ways of solving your problem:

1. You can remove the dependency of one of the package from **pom.xml** which would 
   remove the package from referenced libraries.
2. Otherwise, if both packages are necessary for you then, you need to provide full 
   qualified package name.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same package name like `com.mongodb` will not create any issue as long as the class name is unique. If both the jars have the same class name as `ConnectionString` but in different packages, use the fully qualified class name like `com.mongodb.ConnectionString` wherever referring to the corresponding class. If both the jars contain the same class name in the similar package, then you may end up something like `NoSuchMethodError` while accessing a particular method.